# How to handle application failure after reading event from source in Spring Cloud Stream with rabbit MQ

Tags: event-handling, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Stream over RabbitMQ for my project. I have a processor that reads from a source, process the message and publish it to the sink. 
Is my understanding correct that if my application picks up an event from the stream and fails (e.g. app sudden death):

- unless I ack the message or
- I save the message after reading it from the queue

then my event would be lost? What other option would I have to make sure not to lose the event in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIgging through the Rabbit-MQ documentation I found [this very useful example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) page for the different types of queues and message deliveries for RabbitMQ, and most of them can be used with AMPQ.
In particular looking at the [work queue example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) for java, I found exactly the answer that I was looking for:

> **Message acknowledgment**
>
> Doing a task can take a few seconds. **You may wonder what happens if
>   one of the consumers starts a long task and dies with it only partly
>   done. With our current code, once RabbitMQ delivers a message to the
>   consumer it immediately marks it for deletion. In this case, if you
>   kill a worker we will lose the message it was just processing. We'll
>   also lose all the messages that were dispatched to this particular
>   worker but were not yet handled. But we don't want to lose any tasks.
>   If a worker dies, we'd like the task to be delivered to another
>   worker.**
>
> In order to make sure a message is never lost, RabbitMQ supports
>   message acknowledgments. An ack(nowledgement) is sent back by the
>   consumer to tell RabbitMQ that a particular message has been received,
>   processed and that RabbitMQ is free to delete it.
>
> If a consumer dies (its channel is closed, connection is closed, or
>   TCP connection is lost) without sending an ack, RabbitMQ will
>   understand that a message wasn't processed fully and will re-queue it.
>   If there are other consumers online at the same time, it will then
>   quickly redeliver it to another consumer. That way you can be sure
>   that no message is lost, even if the workers occasionally die.
>
> There aren't any message timeouts; RabbitMQ will redeliver the message
>   when the consumer dies. It's fine even if processing a message takes a
>   very, very long time.
>
> Manual message acknowledgments are turned on by default. In previous
>   examples we explicitly turned them off via the autoAck=true flag. It's
>   time to set this flag to false and send a proper acknowledgment from
>   the worker, once we're done with a task.

Thinking about it, using the ACK seems to be the logic thing to do. The reason why I didn't think about it before, is because I thought of a ACK just under the perspective of the publisher and not of the broker. The piece of documentation above was very useful to me.